# Generating federated tables dynamically in mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, federated

I have server-1 and has database demo and have 10 tables.
I have server-2 and has database feddemo.
I have to generate federated tables in server-2 from demo database.

How can this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

There is a how to manual on MySQL site -

[How to Create FEDERATED Tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-create.html)